# Making sense of the message "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"

Tags: .net

This isn't a question about a specific problem where I see this error message. I am trying to understand the rationale behind the .NET architects who decided to create this error message in the first place. What exactly is meant here by "the target of an invocation"? I understand "invocation" is as in "function invocation", but what is "the target" of that?

Comment: This error is being thrown by code that was invoked through .NET reflection, typical during late-binding on runtime. See [this blog post](https://blog.fredrikhaglund.se/blog/2009/12/22/debugging-exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation/) for a decent explanation.